# Is it possible to get rid of {NewItemPlaceholder} when binding DataGrid to ObservableCollection without losing functionality?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` I bound to an `ObservableCollection`. The grid is configured in a way that the user can add rows (this is the desired behavior). Elsewhere in my GUI, I bound the same collection to be the `ItemsSource` of a `ComboBox`. There, it shows the `{NewItemPlaceholder}` I don't want.

I found a similar question where it is suggested to set `CanUserAddRows` to `false` but then I would need a dedicated button or context menu item to add a new row which I find less intuitive.

So, is there a way to get rid of this placeholder by e.g. some means of filtering the `ItemsSource`?

**Followup 1**

I discovered the following strange behavior:

- When I directly bind the `ItemsSource` of the combo box to the observable collection, I get the `{NewItemPlaceholder}`
- When I declare a `CollectionViewSource` as a `Resource` of my combo box, set its `Source` to the observable collection and set in turn my `CollectionViewSource` as the `ItemsSource` of the combo box, the `{NewItemPlaceholder}` disappears. I don't even have to specify a filter.

Comment: Create and show the code for a test project which we on StackOverflow can use as a reference. Calling something a bug may be a stretch depending on the actual usage.

Comment: I am now going with the `CollectionViewSource` workaround which works well, but you are right, I removed the line about the bug in my above posting.